# How do I round a number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, numbers, rounding

While working on a project, I came across a JS-script created by a former employee that basically creates a report in the form of

```
Name : Value
Name2 : Value2
```

etc.

The peoblem is that the values can sometimes be floats (with different precision), integers, or even in the form `2.20011E+17`. What I want to output are pure integers. I don't know a lot of JavaScript, though.  How would I go about writing a method that takes these sometimes-floats and makes them integers?

Comment: I'd also recommend calling Math.floor() before so it doesn't round up if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You hav to convert your input into a number and then round them:

```
function toInteger(number){ 
  return Math.round(  // round to nearest integer
    Number(number)    // type cast your input
  ); 
};
```

Or as a one liner:

```
function toInt(n){ return Math.round(Number(n)); };
```

Testing with different values:

```
toInteger(2.5);           // 3
toInteger(1000);          // 1000
toInteger("12345.12345"); // 12345
toInteger("2.20011E+17"); // 220011000000000000
```

Comment: The one liner is exactly the same as the 4 liner :)

Comment: The actual one-liner is 'Math.round(number)'. The whole type casting business is unnecessary. In JavaScript strings are automatically coerced to numbers when needed.

Comment: @AaronAsAChimp I can't agree - if the string includes other characters than digits and `.` or `E+` then `Math.round` will return `NaN`.

Comment: On the contrary, the `Number` function uses the same algorithm for converting numbers as coercion. 

The algorithm (Defined in Section 9.3.1 of ECMA-262 3rd edition) handles a wide variety of formats. Basically anything that would be a valid number, including decimals, exponent notation, and hexadecimal. (seriously `'0xFF' == 255`)

Answer (score 103):

If you need to round to a certain number of digits use the following function

```
function roundNumber(number, digits) {
            var multiple = Math.pow(10, digits);
            var rndedNum = Math.round(number * multiple) / multiple;
            return rndedNum;
        }
```

Comment: It might be better to use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), added in JavaScript 1.5.

Comment: Note that toFixed() outputs a string. `(0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(2)` yields the string "0.30". But you can get it back into a number by prepending "+". `+(0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(2)` yields the number 0.3

Comment: if you are using lodash u can [lodash's round function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#round): `_.round(number, precision)`

Comment: Actually I think that what @qwertz suggests is the best answer you can get on SO.

Answer (score 30):

According to the [ECMAScript specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-4.3.20), numbers in JavaScript are represented only by the double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754. Hence there is not really an integer type in JavaScript.

Regarding the rounding of these numbers, there are a number of ways you can achieve this. The [Math](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.8) object gives us three rounding methods wich we can use:

The [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) is most commonly used, it returns the value rounded to the nearest integer. Then there is the [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) wich returns the largest integer less than or equal to a number. Lastly we have the [Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) function that returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a number.

There is also the [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) that returns a string representing the number using fixed-point notation.

Ps.: There is **no 2nd argument** in the *Math.round()* method. The *toFixed()* is **not IE specific**, its [within](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.7.4) the ECMAScript specification aswell

Comment: Good explanation and my bad for supplying the second arguement; I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You just have to go for the spec =]

Answer (score 25):

Here is a way to be able to use `Math.round()` with a second argument (number of decimals for rounding):

```
// 'improve' Math.round() to support a second argument
var _round = Math.round;
Math.round = function(number, decimals /* optional, default 0 */)
{
  if (arguments.length == 1)
    return _round(number);

  var multiplier = Math.pow(10, decimals);
  return _round(number * multiplier) / multiplier;
}

// examples
Math.round('123.4567', 2); // => 123.46
Math.round('123.4567');    // => 123
```

Answer (score 20):

You can also use `toFixed(x)` or `toPrecision(x)` where *x* is the number of digits.

Both these methods are supported in all major browsers

Answer (score 16):

You can use [Math.round()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_math.asp) for rounding numbers to the nearest integer.

```
Math.round(532.24) => 532
```

Also, you can use [parseInt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp) and [parseFloat()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp) to cast a variable to a certain type, in this case integer and floating point.

Comment: So Math.round(532.24,0) = 532?

Comment: Math.round() does not have a second argument, as it rounds the number to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 0):

A very good approximation for rounding:

```
function Rounding (number, precision){

var newNumber;
var sNumber = number.toString();

var increase = precision + sNumber.length - sNumber.indexOf('.') + 1;

if (number < 0)
  newNumber = (number -  5 * Math.pow(10,-increase));
else
  newNumber = (number +  5 * Math.pow(10,-increase));

var multiple = Math.pow(10,precision);

return Math.round(newNumber * multiple)/multiple;
}
```

Only in some cases when the length of the decimal part of the number is very long will it be incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Math.floor(19.5) = 19  should also work.

Comment: Floor != round. `floor(19.5) == 19`, but `round(19.5) = 20`.