# Rounding JavaScript calculation

Tags: javascript

I have three input boxes in a form and use two of them to perform a simple calculation with the result in the third input box. These are then all put into a database to be used elsewhere. Here is my code for the calculation.

```
document.insert_moves.elements.number1.value = ((document.insert_moves.elements.biomass1.value * 1000)/ document.insert_moves.elements.weight1.value);
```

How can I make this so it rounds down to the nearest whole number? Any advice appreciated.

Comment: You Google `javascript round down` http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+round+down&sugexp=chrome,mod=10&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246193/how-do-i-round-a-number-in-javascript

Comment: Yeah had a look at the other questions Bob, even tried a few of the solutions, but I could not get them to work.

Should have mentioned I am a javascript noob and just need to know how to format the code as nothing I am trying is working.

Answer (score 5):

Math.floor(); should do the trick

Comment: Math.floor() was my first thought, but not sure how to format the code.

Sorry, should have mentioned I am a relative noob to javascript.

Answer (score 3):

A bit faster if you're just trying to round down is to use the bitwise |

```
var roundedDown = 5.672391 | 0;
```

it's also surprisingly fast to use this to round to a specific number of digits like

```
var roundedTo2Digits = ((5.8273487 * 100) | 0) / 100;
```

Comment: Thanks - very helpful.  For some reason I could get Math.round to work in my equation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()`. Since you want to round it *down*, its the latter.

Comment: Math.floor() was my first thought, but not sure how to format the code. Sorry, should have mentioned I am a relative noob to javascript