# Simple movement calculation gives wrong result

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have this function.

```
    Calculations.add(this, //CONTEXT
        function () { //CALUCATE
            this.position.x += (this.movementSpeed.x / 10);
        }, 
        function () { //HAVE CALCULATED
            return (this.position.x === (tempX + this.movementSpeed.x));
        }
    );
```

I have run the result, but sometime the result is wrong. Cause I know that if it calculate 10 times, then the the `HAVE CALCULATED` whould be true.

But sometimes it never is... And that kills my app.

Let us say that the result should give 138, then after the calculation it give me 138.000000000006 which is not 138 and the `HAVE CALCULATED` is false..

How can I manage this= I can't use round, because it should be able to return 138.5, if the end-result is that.

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: This is expected behavior inherent in floating-point numbers. Please read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html . Truncate your numbers to a certain number of decimal places to mitigate floating-point error.

Comment: I have to take some time out for that, 112 pages is a lot. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never compare floating point values this way. (The link from Waleed Khan in the comments gives a good explanation why this happens)

Instead you can do something like this to check equality of `a` and `b`:

```
if (a < b + 0.0001 && a > b - 0.0001) {
  // values are "equal"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always floating point = comparisons should be done like this:

`Math.abs( a - b ) < 1e-6`

where `1e-6` is an arbitrary error threshold that you determine in advance

Comment: Generally called `epsilon` or something, after the hardware-limit [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon).

Comment: After taking a quick look at http://www.beastin.name/professional/Threshold%20estimates%20for%20arbitrary%20error%20models.pdf I don't think I am capable of doing this comparison. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could round to a certain number of digits, from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246193/how-do-i-round-a-number-in-javascript) on SO use something like this:

```
function roundNumber(n, digits) {
  var multiple = Math.pow(10, digits);
  return Math.round(n * multiple) / multiple;;
}
```

This way you do not require fancy comparisons.

Comment: How would you determine the digits number?

Comment: It is up to you, as per your question "because it should be able to return 138.5", digits would be 1. You decide at what level you want to round.