# How to multiply in Javascript? problems with decimals

Tags: javascript, decimal, multiplication

i've the following code in Javascript:

```
var m1 = 2232.00;
var percent = (10/100);
var total = percent*m1;
alert(total);
```

The problem is that the variable "total" gives me "223.20000000000002" and it should be "223.2", what should i do to get the correct value?

Comment: This may be the answer you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: Or more information dealing with [rounding numbers in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246193/how-do-i-round-a-number-in-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 31):

**.toFixed()** is best solution.It will keep only two digits after dot.

**Exp 1:**

```
var value = 3.666;
value.toFixed(2); //Output : 3.67
```

**Exp 2:**

```
var value = 3.0000;
value.toFixed(2); //Output : 3.00
```

Comment: Note, `.toFixed(n)` results in a **string** not a decimal value... so using `+` or `+=` will concatenate, not add to the variable

Answer (score 8):

You can't get the exact value. This is the fundamental problem with floating-point numbers.

You can force a fixed number of decimal numbers with `toFixed`:

```
alert(total.toFixed(2));
```

However, keep in mind that this will leave trailing zeroes, which you might not want. You can remove them with `.replace(/0+$/,'');`

Comment: You probably will also want to `.replace(/.$/, '')` after  `.replace(/0+$/, '')` to get rid of any trailing decimal point if there is one.

Comment: The `.replace(/.$/, '')` wont work try using `.replace(/\.$/, '')`

Answer (score 7):

If you are trying to display this number, you could convert to a string with [toFixed(1)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp). If you do this, keep track of the types because you can't then multiply the string with another number.

If you are going to use it in another computation you could truncate it to one decimal place:

```
Math.round( total * 10 ) / 10
```

However, as pointed out by various people, the inexact value is just the way floating point numbers are.

See the questions linked in the comments for more good information.

Comment: the fact is that i don't need to convert this value to String because i need to use the variable "total" to multiply with another one.

Comment: You can do it safely as it is. This is the way floating-point numbers are in JS, MSVC++ float or double too.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer using the following pages, thanks to [Dimitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27073/dimitry):

[Floating-point cheat sheet for JavaScript](http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/javascript/)

I decided to use the following clases because i need the exact values of the operations and they're related to money operations:

- https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js
- https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Comment: bignumber.js is now on the [jsdelivr CDN](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!bignumber.js)

Answer (score 5):

The operator "*" and "/" do not work perfectly always, for example:

```
32.09 * 100 = 3209.0000000000005
100 / (1 / 32.09) = 3209.0000000000005
```

**Solution:**

One solution, the easy one, to have decimals is useing .toFixed(2) where "2" is the number of decimal digits that you want. But you have to take into account this return you a String, and it rounds the value.

```
45.6789.toFixed(2) —> "45.68" as String
```

Other option, the most complete, is using .toLocaleString that converts the number properly to the country code that you want. You can set a pair of params to fix the decimals values always to 2. This also returns you a String:

```
(654.3453).toLocaleString(
  'en-US',
  {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2},
) —> "654.35" as String
```

If you need it as a Number, you can wrap it into Number( ... ) :

```
Number((654.3453).toLocaleString(
  'en-US',
  {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2},
)) —> 654.35 as Number
```

If you only want a no decimal number, use one of this methods to be sure that the result is without decimals.

```
Math.trunc(32.09); —> 32 as Number  
(32.09).toFixed(0); —> “32” as String
32.09 | 0; —> 32 as Number
```

Answer (score 4):

I ended up with the following solution:

```
function decimalmultiply(a, b) {
    return parseFloat((a * b).toFixed(12));
}

10.50*30.45=319.72499999999997
decimalmultiply(10.50,30.45)=319.725
```

This method returns a **number**, not a **string**, without truncating significant decimals (up to 12).

Answer (score 3):

`total.toFixed(2)` may help. But note that the `total` variable be will typecasted into a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 3):

This can be done well with an external library called [decimal.js](http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) that provides a `Decimal` type for JavaScript. It's also available for Node on npm. Below is an example that replicates the original example from *gustavomanolo* using decimal.js.

```js
// Decimal type provided by decimal.js (http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/)
var m1 = new Decimal( 2232.00 );
var percent = new Decimal( 10/100 );
var total = m1.mul(percent);
console.log( 'Total:', total );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/7.2.3/decimal.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a work around solution for multiplication of floating numbers. It's pretty simple but works for me. You figure out how many decimals the numbers have with this function.

```
function decimalPlaces(num) {
    var match = (''+num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
    if (!match) { return 0; }
    return Math.max(
        0,
        // Number of digits right of decimal point.
        (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0)
        // Adjust for scientific notation.
        - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0));
}
```

And then for your final answer "total" you do

```
total = total.toFixed(decimalPlaces(a)+decimalPlaces(b));
```

where a,b are your numbers

Comment: credits to Mike Samuel from post [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454518/javascript-how-to-retrieve-the-number-of-decimals-of-a-string-number) for the decimalPlaces function

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
var x = 0.07;
console.log((x+1)*100 - 100);
```

now, replace the value of x for the other values 
;-)

Comment: It doesn't work properly Eg. take x = 0.041

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
var total = +(percent*m1).toPrecision(15);

223.2 === total;          // true
223.2 === 0.1*2232.00;    // false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular, I made a component for this.

Install with bower

```
bower install angular-floating-point --save
```

Usage

```
var pretty = floatingPoint.makePretty(6.1*6);
```

> Here is a demo -> https://mattspaulding.github.io/angular-floating-point
>   Here is source -> https://github.com/mattspaulding/angular-floating-point

Try it yourself with this snippet below.

```js
 angular.module('myApp', ['floatingPoint'])
  .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, floatingPoint) {

      $scope.calculate = function () {
        $scope.result =$scope.num0*$scope.num1;
        $scope.prettyResult=floatingPoint.makePretty($scope.result)
      }

      $scope.num0=6.1;
      $scope.num1=6;
      $scope.calculate();

    });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Angular App</title>
  <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mattspaulding/angular-floating-point/master/dist/angular-floating-point.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 10px;text-align:center">
      <label>(try me) ==> </label>
      <input ng-model="num0" ng-change="calculate()" style="width:100px; height:30px">
      X
      <input ng-model="num1" ng-change="calculate()" style="width:100px; height:30px">
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px;">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label style="float: right;">Ugly calculation:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label style="float: left;">{{result}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px;">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label style="float: right;"><span style="color:blue">Angular Floating Point</span> calculation:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label style="float: left;">{{prettyResult}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution. The `*` operator is a bit broken when it comes to decimal numbers, but the `/` operator is not. A multiplication can be easily transformed into a division since a • b = a / (1/b)

```
function times(a, b) { return a/(1/b) }
```

Just replace `percent * m1` with `times(percent, m1)`.

**Update:** It doesn't work all the times.

Comment: It doesn't works: 32.09 * 100 = 3209.0000000000005  
100 / (1 / 32.09) = 3209.0000000000005

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps... it took me a while to get there but it kinda does the trick.

```
Number.prototype.CountDecimals = function () {
  if (Math.floor(this.valueOf()) === this.valueOf())
    return 0;
  return this.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0;
};

String.prototype.PadRight = function (fullLength, character) {
  if (String.isNullOrEmpty(this.toString()) || String.isNullOrEmpty(character))
    return this.toString();
  var value = this.toString();
  while (value.length < fullLength)
    value += character;
  return value;
};

var Multiply = function () {
  var maxNumberOfDecimals = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var decimals = arguments[i].CountDecimals();
    if (decimals > maxNumberOfDecimals)
      maxNumberOfDecimals=decimals;
  }
  var results = 1;
  for (var j = 0; j < arguments.length; j++) {
    var arg = arguments[j];
    arg = arg * parseFloat('1'.PadRight(maxNumberOfDecimals + 1, '0'));
    results = results * arg;
  }
  var divisor = parseFloat('1'.PadRight((maxNumberOfDecimals * arguments.length) +1, '0'));
  return results / divisor;
};
```