# how to perform a rounding function to converted currencies using java script??

Tags: javascript

I am looking  to perform a rounding function to converted currencies . My base currency is USD and I have 4 other currencies in my shop that when converted will show figures with cents. I would like to round off the cents and just display the dollars. i.e. £46.23 becomes £46.00 
 how can i do that??`
the code for currencies conversion is here but how can i perform rounding function??

```js
var Currency = {
  rates: {"USD":1.0,"EUR":1.18235,"GBP":1.31967,"CAD":0.799475,"ARS":0.056668,"AUD":0.799924,"BRL":0.319752,"CLP":0.0015396,"CNY":0.148679,"CYP":0.397899,"CZK":0.045321,"DKK":0.158978,"EEK":0.0706676,"HKD":0.128031,"HUF":0.00388777,"ISK":0.00968573,"INR":0.0155764,"JMD":0.00784505,"JPY":0.00906149,"LVL":1.57329,"LTL":0.320236,"MTL":0.293496,"MXN":0.05614,"NZD":0.750685,"NOK":0.126912,"PLN":0.277962,"SGD":0.737474,"SKK":21.5517,"SIT":175.439,"ZAR":0.0758898,"KRW":0.000893297,"SEK":0.123782,"CHF":1.03379,"TWD":0.033088,"UYU":0.0353508,"MYR":0.233519,"BSD":1.0,"CRC":0.00174918,"RON":0.259244,"PHP":0.0198146,"AED":0.272236,"VEB":9.89339e-05,"IDR":7.54055e-05,"TRY":0.284221,"THB":0.0300444,"TTD":0.148204,"ILS":0.280674,"SYP":0.00193866,"XCD":0.37037,"COP":0.000334991,"RUB":0.0167319,"HRK":0.159568,"KZT":0.00303551,"TZS":0.000446743,"XPT":938.274,"SAR":0.266651,"NIO":0.0332101,"LAK":0.000121029,"OMR":2.59991,"AMD":0.00208964,"CDF":0.000621197,"KPW":0.00785056,"SPL":6.0,"KES":0.00962681,"ZWD":0.00276319,"KHR":0.000244875,"MVR":0.0649291,"GTQ":0.137316,"BZD":0.499861,"BYR":5.18136e-05,"LYD":0.742597,"DZD":0.00922372,"BIF":0.000576935,"GIP":1.31967,"BOB":0.14458,"XOF":0.00180248,"STD":4.81573e-05,"NGN":0.00317224,"PGK":0.311604,"ERN":0.0652089,"MWK":0.00137597,"CUP":0.0377358,"GMD":0.0217887,"CVE":0.0106932,"BTN":0.0155764,"XAF":0.00180248,"UGX":0.00027751,"MAD":0.105962,"MNT":0.000409398,"LSL":0.0758898,"XAG":16.8011,"TOP":0.463099,"SHP":1.31967,"RSD":0.0098333,"HTG":0.0159471,"MGA":0.000338915,"MZN":0.0163846,"FKP":1.31967,"BWP":0.0986293,"HNL":0.0427342,"PYG":0.000179987,"JEP":1.31967,"EGP":0.0558817,"LBP":0.000663732,"ANG":0.559923,"WST":0.404114,"TVD":0.799924,"GYD":0.00486085,"GGP":1.31967,"NPR":0.00974728,"KMF":0.00240331,"IRR":3.06527e-05,"XPD":884.12,"SRD":0.134302,"TMM":5.77104e-05,"SZL":0.0758898,"MOP":0.124302,"BMD":1.0,"XPF":0.00990809,"ETB":0.0429183,"JOD":1.41168,"MDL":0.0552733,"MRO":0.00278276,"YER":0.00399645,"BAM":0.604526,"AWG":0.558659,"PEN":0.308586,"VEF":0.0989339,"SLL":0.000132348,"KYD":1.21951,"AOA":0.00602612,"TND":0.41731,"TJS":0.113649,"SCR":0.0736818,"LKR":0.00651173,"DJF":0.00561332,"GNF":0.000111298,"VUV":0.00918435,"SDG":0.150282,"IMP":1.31967,"GEL":0.417684,"FJD":0.497719,"DOP":0.0210853,"XDR":1.41115,"MUR":0.0298276,"MMK":0.000735698,"LRD":0.0111047,"BBD":0.5,"ZMK":0.000112534,"XAU":1267.75,"VND":4.40005e-05,"UAH":0.038752,"TMT":0.288552,"IQD":0.000857625,"BGN":0.604054,"KGS":0.0145672,"RWF":0.00119319,"BHD":2.65229,"UZS":0.000244156,"PKR":0.00948842,"MKD":0.0192137,"AFN":0.014605,"NAD":0.0758898,"BDT":0.0122913,"AZN":0.592208,"SOS":0.00172763,"QAR":0.273189,"PAB":1.0,"CUC":1.0,"SVC":0.114286,"SBD":0.128467,"ALL":0.00889658,"BND":0.737474,"KWD":3.31396,"GHS":0.226607,"ZMW":0.112534,"XBT":2866.01,"NTD":0.0337206,"BYN":0.518136},
  convert: function(amount, from, to) {
    return (amount * this.rates[from]) / this.rates[to];
  }
};
```

`

Comment: Have you tried anything so far on your own yet? Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO! How about `Math.round(Currency.convert(46.23, 'USD', 'GBP'));`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I round a number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246193/how-do-i-round-a-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round to the nearest number without decimals you can use Math.round(num), but if you want to round to the nearest number less than the original you can use Math.floor(num):

```
console.log(Math.round(46.23)); // 46
console.log(Math.round(46.73)); // 46

console.log(Math.floor(46.23)); // 46
console.log(Math.floor(46.23)); // 46
```

If you want to add two zeroes to get two decimals use num.toFixed(2)

```
console.log(Math.round(46.23).toFixed(2)); // 46.00
console.log(Math.round(46.73).toFixed(2)); // 46.00

console.log(Math.floor(46.23).toFixed(2)); // 46.00
console.log(Math.floor(46.23).toFixed(2)); // 46.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.round()`.

```
console.log(Math.round(46.23)) //46
```